# Trying to create Atlas search index but getting 401 error

Tags: mongodb, search, indexing

I am trying to create atlas search index from code. I am Getting error while creating error according to procedure given by mongodb atlas documentation. [Documentation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/reference/api-resources-spec/#tag/Atlas-Search/operation/createAtlasSearchIndex)

Getting this in response

```
    "error": 401,
    "reason": "Unauthorized",
    "detail": "You are not authorized for this resource."
```

Example url: [https://cloud.mongodb.com/api/atlas/v1.0/groups/{groupId}/clusters/{clusterName}/fts/indexes](https://cloud.mongodb.com/api/atlas/v1.0/groups/%7BgroupId%7D/clusters/%7BclusterName%7D/fts/indexes)

I extracted groupId and clusterName from my connection string URI. But still getting this error message. Am I doing anything wrong here?

I tried reading documentation and framed endpoint in the given way. But still I am getting error. I am expecting it to create a search index on atlas